# ArcGIS 10.2 Debug with Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, crash, arcgis

I am attempting to debug a custom plugin that was developed so that I can track down some errors that is causing ArcGIS to crash.

My problem is that whenever I set up a breakpoint I get "No symbols have been loaded for this document"

So I tried placing in a Stop point so I can step through after a known event e.g. Mouse click

Still ArcGIS crashes and the debug halts entirely.

It almost seems that ArcGIS has just loaded the program in and isn't returning anything back to Visual Studio.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

-UPDATE

I think it may have something to do with the API as it will still run once the debugger has stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to “clean solution” and “rebuild solution”.

"No symbols have been loaded for this document" message shows that your current code does not used in running application.

Comment: Hi Seyyed, I have tried that but it is still showing the message "No symbols have been loaded for this document"